# How to check if MessageSession of service bus is in use by a reader?

Tags: c#, azure, queue, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

My company need a way to "synchronize" data between our customers and a remote service. I am currently reviewing service bus to solve this challenge. The most important part is that synchronization must happen in exact the same order. So lets say that an entity was createad -> updated -> updated -> deleted then it is important that all the messages on the queue will execute in same order.

There will be about 100 writers to the queue where each will write to separate session, so there will be about 100 sessions.

I am trying to have multiple readers read from different sessions.

As i understood when `AcceptMessageSession` is called then the session which is returned by the call is "locked" to the current reader which is what i expect, however when i call `GetMessageSessions` returns locked sessions. Are there any way to make  `GetMessageSessions` only return not locked sessions?

here is client code

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
            Console.WriteLine("Reader Started");

            while (true)
            {
                var lockId = Guid.NewGuid();
                var sessions = client.GetMessageSessions();

                foreach (var item in sessions)
                {
                    StartSessionReading(client, item, lockId);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
```

and here is the method which actually locks session and read from it

```
public static void StartSessionReading(QueueClient client, MessageSession s, Guid lockId)
{

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("started thread");
        try
        {
            var session = client.AcceptMessageSession(s.SessionId, true);

            var x = client.GetMessageSessions();

            var message = session.Receive();
            while (message != null)
            {
                printLine(message, session);
                message = session.Receive(new TimeSpan(5));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    });
}
```